# Angular Template Forms , conditional render some fields based on configuration

Tags: angular, configuration

Question:
I have a template driven form  ,with many fields, in the below format.
I have to display or not display few fields ,based on some JSON (with Country as Keys ).
Is it possible to achieve this with this kind of a structure?

//Sample JSON

```
fieldNottorender =   {  USA: [displayField1,displayField3] , JAPAN: [ displayField2] }
```

//Sample Form

```
<form #sampleForm="ngForm">
    <div class="col-3">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>hello</mat-label> <input matInput name="test1" #test1="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="object1.test1">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>hello</mat-label> <input matInput name="test2" #test2="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="object1.test2">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>hello</mat-label> <input matInput name="test3" #test3="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="object1.test3">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Solution:

One Solution i had was to use a function which returns if the field has to be rendered or not , but in this case *i have to hardcode the field names* in my ngIf condition for every item in the form.
(Assuming the Country is fixed to USA.)
I personally do not like this way of solution.

// Sample Form

```
<form #sampleForm="ngForm">
    <div class="col-3" *ngIf="canRender('displayField1')">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>hello</mat-label> <input matInput name="test1" #test1="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="object1.test1">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3" ***ngIf="canRender('displayField2')" **>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>hello</mat-label> <input matInput name="test2" #test2="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="object1.test2">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3" *ngIf="canRender('displayField3')">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>hello</mat-label> <input matInput name="test3" #test3="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="object1.test3">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</form>
```

//Function to Render

```
canRender(fieldName) {
    return this.fieldNottorender.USA.includes(fieldName)
}
```

Comment: What are test1, test2 and test3? What is object1 for?

Comment: its just a sample :
Object is some object which will be stored to backend and it has some keys as test1,test2 ,test3. 

But in JSON ,its the UI form field name which says which form fields to not render.

Have modified the post ,for clarity (now it has displayField)